# various ip address ranges

Tags: ip-address, virtual-ip-address

What are the various classifications of ip address ranges in existence apart from Class A,B,C and D addressing.
For instance what does the range 212.198.0.255-202.190.0.255 denote in specific?

Answer (score 1):

There ranges are

```
Class   Leftmost bits   Start address   Finish address
A              0xxx     0.0.0.0     127.255.255.255
B              10xx     128.0.0.0   191.255.255.255
C              110x     192.0.0.0   223.255.255.255
```

D & E classes are also present but D class is only Reserved for Multicasting and E class is for Experimental; used for research

```
Class   Leftmost bits   Start address   Finish address

D              1110     224.0.0.0   239.255.255.255
E              1111     240.0.0.0   255.255.255.255
```

Please [follow this link for further detail](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/ip-addresses-explained/)
As you are new to StackOverFlow , Then I must ask you to read the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and must see that How and which question you should ask here.This is a very simple question and You can eaisly find its answer from serach engine.First do your own effort and then ask here if you stuck.GoodLuck

Comment: ip address ranges in existence apart from Class A,B,C and D was my question . .

Comment: OK its my bad.You mean to say that How you can calculate the number of IPs between two ranges like How you can calculate Number of IPs between `212.198.0.255 - 202.190.0.255 `

Comment: No not that, ip addr of few countries will be only be within a specific range . .in similar way is there any other classification . .